# Is it too late to ally with the NCR?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

Now I have been playing a lot of Fallout: New Vegas and I've gotten quite far with the Yes Man quest line (all the way to the quest to get into the electrical station). But I want to join the NCR as my main faction.

I am idolized by the NCR. Is there any way to join the NCR at my state in the game?

Answer (score 4):

By the point you are sabotaging the substation you have passed the point of no return and can no longer switch your ending to NCR. You may still switch between the Yes Man (independent) or House endings, if he is still alive.

You can read more about the NCR’s point of no return from the forewarning [Don’t tread on the Bear](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Don%27t_Tread_on_the_Bear!) quest page.

More specifically, you became locked out of the NCR ending when you either replaced House with Yes Man, met all the factions for Yes Man, or dealt with the Omertas for Mr. House.

You must reload a save to choose an alternate path to remain in the NCR’s good graces and end the game in their favor. If you sneak in while disguised as an NCR soldier or while using a stealth boy you won’t suffer reputation loss after the sabotage, but you still will not be able to proceed with the NCR quest line.